# What does NavMesh.AllAreas specify in Unity?

Tags: unity, navmesh

I'm trying to calculate the path to a point in my game using NavMesh.CalculatePath, it takes an argument NavMesh.AllAreas. I read the Unity Manual and couldn't clearly understand what it meant.

Comment: Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Comment: Nothing for now, will pose a question when I hit one, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

`NavMesh.AllAreas` let you compute a path considering all the [NavMesh Areas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-AreasAndCosts.html) are walkable for your agent.

---

## Long answer

#### Areas and costs

When you build a NavMesh in Unity, you have the possibility to divide it into multiple parts (called areas)

Each of these areas can have a different "cost" (for example, walking on the sand costs more efforts than walking on the grass).

[image]

#### Preventing agents to walk on certain areas

An other possibility is to prevent agents from walking on certain areas by specifying the 2nd argument when calling `NavMesh.CalculatePath` (if you have an enemy able to walk on the water but not another one for example). When specifying `NavMesh.AllAreas`, you allow your agent to find a path on *every* part of your NavMesh. In the `Agent` component, you can tell which areas he can walk on, using the `AreaMask` member.

[image: AreaMask]

#### What is `areaMask` and how do you compute it?

The value of `areaMask` when calling `NavMesh.CalculatePath` is a binary number.
If you take a look at the first image, we have an array of areas. To indicate whether the character can walk on those areas, you have to specify 1 (walkable) or 0 (not walkable).

Supposing you agent can walk on every areas except "Non Walkable" and "Water"

- Layer 0 : "Walkable" => 1
- Layer 1 : "Not walkable" => 0
- Layer 2 : "Jump" => 1
- Layer 3 : "Water" => 0
- Layer 4 : "Door" => 1

Result (from right to left) : 10101

```
  (1 << 0) + (0 << 1) + (1 << 2) + (0 << 3) + (1 << 4)
= 1 + 0 + 4 + 0 + 16
= 21 // Value to specify when calling NavMesh.CalculatePath
```

Now, supposing you agent can walk on every areas except "Non Walkable"

- Layer 0 : "Walkable" => 1
- Layer 1 : "Not walkable" => 0
- Layer 2 : "Jump" => 1
- Layer 3 : "Water" => 1
- Layer 4 : "Door" => 1

Result (from right to left) : 11101

```
  (1 << 0) + (0 << 1) + (1 << 2) + (1 << 3) + (1 << 4)
= 1 + 0 + 4 + 8 + 16
= 29 // Value to specify when calling NavMesh.CalculatePath
```

The `NavMesh` class provides the [`GetAreaFromName`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.GetAreaFromName.html) function to help you computing the values above :

```
int mask = 0 ;
mask += 1 << NavMesh.GetAreaFromName("Walkable");
mask += 0 << NavMesh.GetAreaFromName("Not walkable");
mask += 1 << NavMesh.GetAreaFromName("Jump");
mask += 1 << NavMesh.GetAreaFromName("Water");
mask += 1 << NavMesh.GetAreaFromName("Door");

// Make sure you don't call multiple times the `GetAreaFromName` with the same area name.
```

#### And what about `NavMesh.AllAreas`?

The value of `NavMesh.AllAreas` is `-1`. Converted into the binary format, it is `11111111111111111111111111111111` (32 x `1` because an integer is written on 32 bits). So, if you specify `1` for every areas, you indicate all of them are walkable for your agent.

Source : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-AreasAndCosts.html